# Promise inside for loop with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have code like follow. What i intend to do is: 
1) For loop and call api with sequence.
2) The next for loop iteration only executed after the promise resolve, with a 1 second delay.

I am doing this way but console.log prints nothing. What is the correct way to approach it?

```
const axios = require('axios');

function getData(i){
    return axios.get(`http://www.api.com/${i}`);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        getData(i)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(`successs ${i}`);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`fail ${i}`);
            })
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: So you really want to *start* with a delay of 1 second, even before a request?

Comment: That will trigger _all_ promise fetches in 1 second (well, pending being able to run). See “promise chaining” for how one might adapt it to run as-a-sequence. The most direct conversion would be to call the “setTimeout” only from resolution of a previous promise. Use a function so this can be done recursively.

Comment: Now, for the “not logging” bit. 1. Try logging in getData (to show the promise is indeed created); 2. Change to loop to only go 1..10 (to avoid complications with an excessive number of timers and promises created).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code basically runs 10000000 api requests simultaneously after 1 second delay. You need to chain API calls so they are run after another:

```
    const axios = require('axios');

    function getData(i){
        return axios.get(`http://www.api.com/${i}`);
    }

    function wait(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    function dataLoop() {
       const getOne = (i: number) => {
         if (i < 10000000) {
            getData(i)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(`successs ${i}`);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(`fail ${i}`);
                })
                .then(wait(1000))
                .then(() => getOne(i + 1))
         }
       }
       getOne(0);
    }
    dataLoop();
```

I suggest to try using async/await if possible in your situation, it greatly simplifies things.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    try {
        const res = await getData(i);
        console.log(`successs ${i}`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`fail ${i}`);
    }
    await wait(1000);
}
```

Comment: Wow the code looks very clean on async await compared to promise. I will try it out :D

Comment: @stackdisplay - Please remember that `async/await` is entirely based on promises and does nothing useful without promises.  So, this isn't `async/await` vs. promises.  This is using `async/await` with promises vs. plain promises.  The `async/await` version only works because `getData()` returns a promise that is connected to the asynchronous operation.

Comment: Is there any solution without recursive calling and without `async/await`? b/c `async` reproduces same flow; it ends before getting result.